# $wpdb->insert_id

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb

I'm using  $wpdb->insert to insert data to my plugin table.
How can I get the id of the new line I Just insert. 
Because I have a lot of users that add data to the table I can't use
$wpdb->insert_id 
Because it's not necessary the last one.

Answer (score 14):

There is no other way, but I can not see how you need any other way then this. I believe that the insert ID accessed by $wpdb is the last ID by this instance of WPDB, other inserts should not affect that but I'm not sure.

```
<?php

  $wpdb->insert("QUERY");

  $this_insert = $wpdb->insert_id;

?>
```

Comment: `$wpdb` is global, all queries share the same instance.

Comment: @toscho but does a query by another user influences the insert ID you get back if they insert a query just in between your insert and read out?

Comment: No it doesn't. `$wpdb` is global, but only in this one request, it's not shared between requests of multiple users. As it's also not asynchronous, this will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

$wpdb->insert_id is global withint the database session.  since Wordpress creates a new session per user session this is not a problem, even when using a connection pooling.
the only caveat is that this variable will always have the last inserted auto-increment ID, so you have to check after each insert.
If you really want to capture the list of new inserted records, you can do it inside a stored procedure and capture it in a transaction.  or inside a trigger.